# white-space: nowrap breaks my mobile email design

Tags: html, css, email

Nowrap works perfectly for my navigation bar at the top (taking the whole screen width.) But the rest of the email then appears at a smaller width below the navigation bar (with an unsightly grey bar down each side.) I believe this is because each part of the email is a separate table and so the nowrap is only applying to the first table. But I have a rule for the rest of the email which is `class="deviceWidth"....` so I am not sure why every other section of the email other than navigation fails to appear at the full width. Did try to add a screenshot...but not got enough rep =/...

**The navigation code**

```
<p style="font-size: 10px; color: #272727; font-weight: light; text-align: right;
    font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px 0px;
    font-style:italic; white-space:nowrap">
```

**The mobile width code in every table**

```
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"
    class="deviceWidth">
```

Comment: Show us some code HTML and CSS, unti that we can only guess what your problem is...

Comment: display: block; dude

Comment: display: block  made no difference

Comment: Maybe the `width=580` has something to do with it.